# Using react-redux, what is the best practice to pass a callback function to a generic Component through the redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, callback, modal-dialog

Here's a simple case, I want to create a generic Modal component with a confirm button. Once the button was clicked, it will fire the onConfirm function we provided via the redux state. And the openModal action can be dispatch inside a thunk action.

```
//Example using thunk after click submit a form
const handleSubmitForm = dispatch => e => {
    dispatch(openModal({
       title: "confirm modal",
       onConfirm: () => { /* dispatch other stuff, async etc..)*/ }
    }))
}
```

However, the issue is that the redux suggest not to pass any non-serializable value like function to the state. And when using redux-toolkit, it will generate a error message "A non-serializable value was detected in the state". So I wonder what is the best practice to perform this type of action.

Other use case:

- dispatch a callback function to the state and contact a web socket server. Then the websocket server communicate back with something that trigger the callbcak.

**Simple Modal CodeSanbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-wnytg?file=/src/containers/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is not to do store any functions in redux (though it will technically work).  Instead you should store whatever arguments you need to invoke the callback and use an action creator function to actually make the call.  In your example you might store `modalType`, `modalTitle`, etc.